# Installing Koala (Sass compiler) on Ubuntu 14.04 -

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu, koala

I'm quite new with Linux, please forgive that.
I try to install the Koala package *koala_2.0.4_i386.deb*, via Ubuntu's default package manager. Here's what happens:

```
Selecting previously unselected package koala.
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 222225 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../Bureau/koala_2.0.4_i386.deb ...
Unpacking koala (2.0.4) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of koala:
koala depends on ruby (>= 1.8.7).

dpkg: error processing package koala (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
koala
```

It seems, Koala can't fully install because of my version of Ruby...?
The package manager proposes to "fix" it, by erasing it.
I do have the icon in my app list, but starting it does nothing.

**Though!**

When i check my version of Ruby, this is what i get :

```
ii  libruby1.9.1                                          1.9.3.484-2ubuntu1.2                                amd64        Libraries necessary to run Ruby 1.9.1
ii  ruby                                                  1:1.9.3.4                                           all          Interpreter of object-oriented scripting language Ruby (default version)
ii  ruby1.9.1                                             1.9.3.484-2ubuntu1.2                                amd64        Interpreter of object-oriented scripting language Ruby
```

I used this software a lot under Windows, and i like its friendly UI. I tried installing other solutions anyway, other problems showed up :/ So i'd appreciate a little help for installing this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, for the folks who experience the same issue, the problem with Ruby version during the install **does not actually prevent the installation of koala**. The install actually worked.

To make the launcher icon work, apply the solution in [the FAQ](https://github.com/oklai/koala/wiki/Unable-to-run-Koala-in-Linux) which actually works. Problem is, the package manager will keep on offering to "fix" the software - by erasing it.

Personally I'll live with it.